# CSS: Can't get :hover to work, what am I missing?

Tags: html, css

Below is my code.  I'm going for a text changing effect when I hover onto a search button.  I'm keeping the button background the same and just trying to change the color of the text when hovering.  I'm not sure what i'm missing.  Is there an easier way to achieve this?  The button just stays the pre-hover colors.  I'm out of ideas.

```
.header_search #search-submit {
    width: 80px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 -83px 0 0;
    background: #ff9105; 
    border: 2px solid black; 
    border-left: none; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #008b95;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
            border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

    {{ trans_fast }}

.header_search #search-submit:hover {
    background: #ff9105; 
    color: white
}
```

Comment: Your CSS syntax is incorrect. missing semi-colon & what is `{{ trans_fast }}` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
.header_search #search-submit {
   width: 80px;
   height: 35px;
   margin: 0 -83px 0 0;
   background: #ff9105;
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-left: none;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #008b95;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
   border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

/* dont know about this "{{ trans_fast }}" */

.header_search #search-submit:hover {
    background: #ff9105;
    color: white;
}
```

After editing here, it should look okay, the trans_fast is a very unknown concept to me.  Some of your css properties were vertical and some were horizontal.  Try one or the other but not both at the same time for syntax purposes.  PLUS (you forgot the semicolon for color)

Comment: If trans_fast is something useful, take out the annotations and the words with it to use, i only did it because i was concerned that it would be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `;` and the end of `color: white`

```
.header_search #search-submit:hover {
    background: #ff9105; 
    color: white;
}
```